# how to set multiple headers on sails hook testing using mocha

Tags: testing, sails.js, mocha.js

how to set multiple headers on testing sails?

example :

```
request(sails.hooks.http.app)
.get(endpoint)
.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
.set('Authorization', 'Bearer 12345')
.expect(function(res) {
  console.log(res.body);
})
.end(done);
```

how to .set multiple headers ?